# What is this hemispherical red berry with many drupelets?

Tags: identification, fruits, berries

Here are two pictures of this berry.

What is the name of it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They look a lot like raspberries, but I'm no plant expert: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry

Comment: Details, please: where in the world did you find it? What kind of place? Can we get a picture of a whole leaf and a stem? Does it have thorns or is it smooth? And if possible, make sure the photos are focussed, yours are a bit blurry.

Comment: Probably a member of *rubus*, but if you ask for edibility, we need as many details as possible.

Comment: Other images of the whole plant to see growth habit, plus a clearer picture of the leaves and branches please

Comment: I removed the part about edibility because that's off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see in the photos, it looks like you have a thimbleberry. Thimbleberries are similar in appearance to raspberries, but are typically even more delicate and prone to falling apart. Their leaves are similar in shape to a maple leaf, and can have sawtooth or smooth edges.

Your original question asked about edibility, and they are indeed edible. The ones I have had growing here in Wisconsin are absolutely delicious, but I've heard that the flavor varies a lot and in some places they are dry and tasteless. It is my understanding that there are no poisonous lookalikes for raspberries/thimbleberries, but please make sure you have a positive identification before eating them.

Comment: I flashed on salmonberry but you are correct, Michelle!  Good admonition, too.

Comment: Yes, salmon berries are similar, except for the color of the berry.